# Some query have bugs

Tags: mysql, sql

I built a minigame in php-sql and I have high score too

The high score should be order by score and then by time of user finish the test.

When user finish test and submit his score and time - I run this query and by that find the rate of

```
    SELECT `rate`
    FROM quiz_1_highscore
    WHERE CASE `score` <= ?
        WHEN true THEN 
            CASE `timer` >= ?
                WHEN true THEN true
                WHEN false THEN
                    CASE `score` != ?
                        WHEN true THEN true
                    END
            END
    END
    ORDER BY `score` DESC, `timer` ASC
    LIMIT 1
```

In first and third parameters it's the score, and in the second is time (seconds)

I have that records -

```
    rate    score   time
    25      10      65
    26      10      74
    27      10      74
    28      10      78
```

I make a record of 10 score and 70 seconds - so I supposed to be rated 26
But the query return 27 - WHY?

I checked without LIMIT and it's order - 27 26 28 ...

How can I fix that?

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

I think you want to order it according to `rate` and `LIMIT 1`

```
SELECT `rate`
    FROM quiz_1_highscore
    WHERE CASE `score` <= ?
        WHEN true THEN 
            CASE `timer` >= ?
                WHEN true THEN true
                WHEN false THEN
                    CASE `score` != ?
                        WHEN true THEN true
                    END
            END
    END
    ORDER BY `rate`,`score` DESC, `timer` ASC
    LIMIT 1
```